# Why is ABC interaction completely confounded in this factorial experiment?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, confounding, blocking

Consider a 2^3 factorial design layed out in 2 blocks ,with plot size 4, as follows

Block I: {1,ab,ac,bc}

Block II: {a,b,c,abc}

This is replicated four times.

abc is said to be completely confounded but I can't understand why.
In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHDov.png) image you can see the full design.
I understand what blocking is and I have been following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDHCpyLgP1U) but he fails to explain what is going on.
The only explanation I have is [this from a Reddit thread.](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/eh74y5/i_cant_understand_why_is_abc_completely/fcg36i2?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

> take the block difference of effect which will be same as effect of ABC
>
> So we couldn't differentiate those effects

But this seems very cryptic to me. I don't know what he meant by "block difference of effect"